# Non-interactive configuration of databricks-connect

Tags: databricks, databricks-connect

I am setting up a development environment as a Docker container image. This will allow me and my colleagues to get up and running quickly using it as an interpreter environment. Our intended workflow is to develop code locally and execute it on an Azure Databricks cluster that's connected to various data sources. For this I'm looking into using [databricks-connect](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html).

I am running into the configuration of databricks-connect apparently solely being an interactive procedure. This results in having to run `databricks-connect configure` and supplying various configuration values each time the Docker container image is run, which is likely to become a nuisance.

**Is there a way to configure databricks-connect in a non-interactive way?** This would allow me to include the configuration procedure in the development environments `Dockerfile` and a developer being only required to supply configuration values when (re)building their local development environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - it’s possible, there are different ways for that:

- use shell multi line input, like this (taken from [here](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-cicd-definitelynotademo/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml#L37)) - just need to define correct environment variables:

```sh
echo "y
$databricks_host
$databricks_token
$cluster_id
$org_id
15001" | databricks-connect configure
```

- generate config file directly - it’s just JSON that you need to fill with necessary parameters. Generate it once, look into `~/.databricks-connect` and reuse.

But really you may not need configuration at all - Databricks connect can take information either from environment variables (like `DATABRICKS_ADDRESS`) or Spark configuration (like `spark.databricks.service.address`) - just refer to [official documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#step-2-configure-connection-properties).

Comment: Thanks, the first part of your answer is very helpful and will definitely get the job done!

About the second part: i) I am not aware of a configuration file being created after configuration and which should be possible to create beforehand: do you have any reference for this? ii) Setting environment variables did not work for me, and setting the Spark configuration led me into another interactive session so I abandoned this route. Am I missing something in the official docs?

Comment: Config file is really created after configuration - its name is `~/.databricks-connect`. Regarding environment variables - it’s really strange - I’ve used some time ago and they worked just fine

Comment: Thanks, I did not find this config file before!

Comment: Setting env variables does not work, fails because `databricks-connect` is looking for the `.databricks-connect` file before checking env variables:   

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Config file /home/viadot/.databricks-connect not found. Please run `databricks-connect configure` to accept the end user license agreement and configure Databricks Connect. A copy of the EULA is provided below:

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it was a behaviour change since my answer... Can you try to create an empty file, or file with `{}` content?

Answer (score 0):

Above didn't work for me, this however did:

```py
with open(os.path.expanduser("~/.databricks-connect"), "w") as f:
    json.dump(db_connect_config, f)
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Where `db_connect_config` is a dictionary with the credentials.