# how to pass values to a command in Linux if it is asking yes and other parameters

Tags: linux, shell, databricks, databricks-connect, aws-databricks

I am working on connecting to a data bricks workspace from databricks-connect command using bash script

i have tried the following command to configure

`echo "y $(databricks url) $(token) $(cluster_id) $(org_id) $(port)" | databricks-connect configure`

but iam unable to connect to the databricks

**please suggest me any other linux command  to pass these values(automated)**

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70472119/non-interactive-configuration-of-databricks-connect) seems to be an answer for your question, note that putting `$(<var name>)` makes the shell try and execute the variable instead of substituting with it's value. The syntax you are using is something i only saw in context to Pipelines written as code in azure devops. Assuming everything is run from your local shell, use `$<var name>` instead.